# How to implement a join in a join with Eloquent

Tags: eloquent

I have a question how to combine two joins in Laravel's eloquent. One join also belongs to the other.

The concept is you have timeslots and I want to know how many attendees there for that timeslot.
The challenge is: I want all available timeslots and a booking is only valid when it's done live, not canceled and completed.

With the query below the booking and counting part is fine, but I only get the timeslots with bookings done.

```
 $this->selectRaw('timeslots.id, timeslots.time_from , timeslots.time_till, duration_minutes,
                            count(attendees.id) as bookedSlots, 
                            capacity as total, 
                            capacity - count(attendees.id) as leftTickets')
            ->where('timeslots.project_id', $projectId)
            ->where('invoices.type', '!=', 'IncompleteOrder')
            ->whereDate('time_from', '=', $date)
            ->leftJoin('attendees', function($query)  {
                $query->on('timeslots.id', '=', 'attendees.timeslot_id')
                      ->where('attendees.is_live', '=', 1)
                      ->where('attendees.is_cancelled', '=', 0);
            })
            ->leftJoin('invoices', 'attendees.invoice_id', '=', 'invoices.id')
            ->groupBy('timeslots.id')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a/the solution:

```
 $response = $this->selectRaw('timeslots.id, timeslots.time_from , timeslots.time_till, duration_minutes,
                            count(attendees.id) as bookedSlots, 
                            capacity as total, 
                            capacity - count(attendees.id) as leftTickets')
            ->where('timeslots.project_id', $projectId)
            ->whereDate('time_from', '=', $date)
            ->leftJoin('attendees', function($query)  {
                $query->on('timeslots.id', '=', 'attendees.timeslot_id')
                      ->where('attendees.is_live', '=', 1)
                      ->where('attendees.is_cancelled', '=', 0);
            })
            ->leftJoin('invoices', function($query)  {
                $query->on('invoices.id', '=', 'attendees.invoice_id')
                    ->where('invoices.type', '!=', 'IncompleteOrder');
            })

            ->groupBy('timeslots.id')
            ->get();
```